# AsyncRestTemplate not calling DELETE endpoint

Tags: spring, http-delete, asyncresttemplate

I need to call rest endpoint with delete method in **fire and forget** fashion. I don't care about result.
I am trying to use AsyncRestTemplate but server side is not being called.
If I switch to RestTemplate everything works.
Then I have noticed that when I wait for response

```
AsyncRestTemplate template = new AsyncRestTemplate();
ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> exchange = template.exchange(
    url, 
    HttpMethod.DELETE, 
    new HttpEntity<Object>(headers), 
    String.class
);
exchange.get();
```

it is also working. Calling PUT endpoint works without any problems (don't have to call get() method).
Then, I tried to use timeout since I don't want to wait for response and used

```
    try {
        exchange.get(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        //dirty hack
    }
```

On my machine if I set 1 millisecond timeout there is a 50% chance that endpoint gets called. At 50 millis it gets too 100% chance...

Any ideas what's the problem?

EDIT:

I also tried

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    try {
        exchange.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

which has worked.

```
AsyncRestTemplate template = new AsyncRestTemplate(
     new ConcurrentTaskExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())
);
```

without calling get() method did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you set 1 ms timeout it is very likely that request will in fact timeout, but also client will terminate the connection while handling the timeout.

Try calling it in a thread or create an `ExecutorService` and queue up the requests.

Comment: I have edited question, see if this is what you mean?
My main goal is to dont even bother with result, which works when I call PUT method endpoint. Simple AsyncRestTemplate without calling get() which works. But not with delete method.